While running my react-native app, I get the following error

C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\utils\errors.js:123
throw error;
^
Error: stream.push() after EOF
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:285:30)
at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
at node:internal/webstreams/adapters:496:22
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Readable instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
code: 'ERR_STREAM_PUSH_AFTER_EOF'
}

Node.js v18.10.0
What should I do? I tried upgrading node and reinstalling dependencies

Just an error message without any context or code is utterly useless and we cannot possibly help you ....
